# Probability Over a Long Period of Time

Tags: probability

Four cities **A, B, C & D** are located as vertices of a square **ABCD** and are connected by roads that form the four sides of the square.

Mr. Walker travels thus:

> - If he is at city $i$ in period $t$, then he randomly with probability $1/2$ each, moves to one of the two vertices/cities that are adjacent to city $i$ in period $t + 1$.
> - If Mr. Walker is at city **A** at $t = 0$, what is the probability that he never visits again till ( including ) period $t = 10$ ?.

Comment: Check the [MSE-$\texttt{MathJax}$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $X_t$ the city you are at time $t$. $X_0=A$. $P(X_1\neq A)=1$ as you can either go to $B$ or $D$ but not stay in A. Then $P(X_2\neq A)=(1/2)$ that is moving to $C$ instead of back to $A$. $P(X_3\neq A)=1$ as from $C$ there's no way of moving back to $A$ without going through $B$ or $D$. But then, you're back to the case of $X_2$. There's a pattern for even and odd periods of time. Therefore, if you want to achieve $X_{10}=A$, you'll have (assuming independent movements) 
$$P(\{X_{10}=A\} \cap \{X_i\neq A, \forall 1\leq i <10\})=$$
$$P(X_1\neq A)P(X_2\neq A)\dots P(X_9\neq A)P(X_{10}=A)= \frac{1}{2^5}$$

Where $P(X_{10}=A)=1/2$ comes from the fact that at even numbers you are either at B or D, and thus with probability $1/2$ you finally come back to A.